# Performance issue when allocating an object imported from a DLL

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, dll, visual-studio-debugging

I'm experiencing a very weird issue.
My c++ program uses a DLL that I've written.
This DLL exports a class MyDocument.

```
#ifdef  WIN32
#   if defined(CORE_EXPORTS)
#       define CORE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#   elif defined(MCORE_IMPORTS)
#       define CORE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#   else
#       define CORE_API
#   endif
#else
#   define CORE_API
#endif

    class CORE_API MyDocument
    {
    public:
    ...
    };
```

As my client program attempts to create an array of this object, it takes more than 7 seconds (almost 10)in debug mode.

```
MyDocument *docs = new MyDocuments[550];
```

I read about using _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 in the env variables but it doesn't change anything.

Moreoever, I found out something weird. Instead of exporting the class MyDocument, I put the whole code in the header file so I can use it by just including its header file.
In that case, the same allocation statement is almost instantaneous.

```
MyDocument *docs = new MyDocuments[550];
```

Honnestly, I don't know what's happening there.

Any suggestion ?

My config: XP with VS Express 2008.

Z.

Comment: Please check if the DLL is enabled to be [delay loaded][1]. Maybe it is the time taken to load the DLL once the class is used for the first time?

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx

Comment: OK. I found out what happened. My colleague has included "vld.h" in the main library header. (vld = Visual Leak Detector library) and he forgot to remove it...And in debug mode, it did slow down performances...So, nothing related to C++ allocation or whatever. 
Sorry. The subject is closed.

Answer (score 0):

please check that,whether CORE_EXPORTS or CORE_INPORTS is definetly defined in your complation unit which include that header file.